# Icons meaning in Awesome Kingdom: The Tower of Hateskull

Tags: awesome-kingdom

All the cards in in *Awesome Kingdom* feature a color-coded gem on the top.

Some of them have icons in the gem but I couldn't find their meaning in the rulebook or any card mentioning them...
I'm talking about the icons on the 6 leftmost cards on the picture below:

[image: Awesome Kingdom cards]

The *Khan of Cons* card was labelled as a bonus for the first print run of the game and is the only card with this icon so I assume it means goodie or something like that. The other 5 cards (plus some other in the game) all feature a crowned skull icon.
Does anyone have an idea of its meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few games, I believe we came to a conclusion about those icons...
So I'll try and answer my own question (I hope it's OK ;-))

Some of the cards with the icons are thematically connected to the Tower of Hateskull Location (Lord Hateskull, Lady Hateskull and the Stick of 6 parts to name a few). I wouldn't be surprised if the plan is to later release expansion packs for the game featuring new locations with associated cards. Those icons would then come in handy to remove all the cards from the Tower of Hateskull Theme set and replace them with the new ones, only leaving the basic ones and one scenario at a time...

Comment: Not sure why this post came back up, but I suppose that's the correct answer... Not sure if it's OK to accept one self answer, just shoot a comment if it's not the case ;-)